# Mysql Trigger Syntax Error(MySql Error?)

Tags: mysql, syntax, triggers

I am trying to get the following trigger into MySql, but I always get an Syntax Error.

I changed the delimiter to `$$`, but I get `Syntax Error 1064` anyway.
The message points to `FOR EACH ROW`.

I can't figure out why.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `upd2_anwendung`
BEFORE UPDATE ON `anwendung`
FOR EACH ROW
INSERT INTO `history` (
kunden_name,
instance,
`database`,
db2_version,
db2_fixpack,
kunde,
klasse,
dpf,
sap,
zeitstempel,
home_dir,
bemerkungen,
install_vz,
port,
changezeit,
changetype
)
values(
old.kunden_name ,
old.instance ,
old.database ,
old.db2_version ,
old.db2_fixpack ,
old.kunde ,
old.klasse ,
old.dpf ,
old.sap ,
old.zeitstempel ,
old.home_dir ,
old.bemerkungen ,
old.install_vz ,
old.port,
current timestamp,
'U'
);
; $$
```

Comment: Well...
I found out why.
I tried to make 2 Triggers for Before Update On

Answer (score 0):

The trigger is missing `begin end` and also the delimiter at the beginning. Something as

```
delimiter //

CREATE TRIGGER `upd2_anwendung` BEFORE UPDATE ON `anwendung`
FOR EACH ROW
begin

    INSERT INTO `history` (
    kunden_name,
    instance,
    `database`,
    db2_version,
    db2_fixpack,
    kunde,
    klasse,
    dpf,
    sap,
    zeitstempel,
    home_dir,
    bemerkungen,
    install_vz,
    port,
    changezeit,
    changetype
    )
    values(
    old.kunden_name ,
    old.instance ,
    old.database ,
    old.db2_version ,
    old.db2_fixpack ,
    old.kunde ,
    old.klasse ,
    old.dpf ,
    old.sap ,
    old.zeitstempel ,
    old.home_dir ,
    old.bemerkungen ,
    old.install_vz ,
    old.port,
    now(),
    'U'
    );
end ; //

delimiter ;
```

Comment: The Delimiter is changed to $$ so thats not missing.

Comment: I see that the end of your code but you need to have on the top as well. I just used a different one in the given answer.